# Base class method calling the Derived class method when using super. Very confused

Tags: python, super

This seems very confusing to me. 
Could someone explain why this unknown magical things happening ?

```
class A(object):
    def testA(self):
        print "TestA of A"
        self.testB()

    def testB(self):
        print "TestB of A"

class B(A):
    def testA(self):
        super(B, self).testA()
        print "TestA of B"
        self.testB()

    def testB(self):
        print "TestB of B"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = B()
    test.testA()
```

```
    Program Output:
    ===============
    TestA of A
    TestB of B --> Why it is calling derived class method ?
    TestA of B
    TestB of B

    Expected Output:
    ================
    TestA of A
    TestB of A -- I want to see A here.
    TestA of B
    TestB of B
```

Your answer will be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

In `A.testA`, you call `self.testB`.  This means to call the "leaf" definition of `testB` for the current instance.  Since `self` is an instance of `testB`, it calls `B.testB`.

Even though you wrote `self.testB` inside a method defined on class `A`, that does not mean it will call the version of the method defined on class `A`.  You are calling the method on the *instance*, and at runtime the class of the instance is determined dynamically, and whatever method is defined on the instance is what will get run.  Since the instance is of class `B`, and class `B` overrides `testA`, the instance's version of `testA` is the one provided by `B`.

If in `A.testA` you want to call `A.testB`, you have to do that explicitly by calling `A.testB(self)`.  However, you should think about why you want to do that.  The whole point of overriding methods is so that you can change how a class does things.  `A` should not need to know which version of `testB` is called.  It should just need to know that it is calling a method called `testB` that does whatever the method `testB` is documented to do in your program/library.  If `A` specifically requires that its own `testB` method be called, this makes it difficult for subclasses to alter the behavior of `testB`, because `A` will ignore their overrides and keep calling its own version instead.

Comment: Thank You. Is there any resolution of this problem ? I mean how to call the "testB()" of base class in this situation ?

Comment: @user968677: I added some more to my answer.  However, you should think carefully before doing that, because if you do that you will introduce un-overridable behavior into your class, which works against the whole concept of overriding methods to change behavior.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand. Perhaps I forgot about the overriding behavior. I will create different local method for each of them for calling its own version. Thank You.